# Php mail being sent from simple POST request but not when using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, email, openshift

So I have a website with a simple contact form and I would like to receive the message by email.

I created my mail.php handler :

```
<?php
    $owner_email = "somebody@somemail.com";
    $headers = 'From:' . $_POST["email"];
    $subject = 'A message from your site visitor ' . $_POST["name"];
    $messageBody = "";

    // some verifications

    try{
        if(!mail($owner_email, $subject, $messageBody, $headers)){
            throw new Exception('mail failed');
        }
        else{
            echo 'mail sent';
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage() ."\n";
    }
?>
```

If I create a simple HTML form like this :

```
<form method="post" action="mail.php">

    <label>Name</label>
    <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">

    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">

    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>

    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

everything works fine and I receive the email in my mailbox.

If I send a POST request from my browser at http://mywebsite.com/mail.php the answer is "mail sent" and I receive the email in my mailbox.

However when I want to use some JavaScript to dynamically validate the form fields and then send the POST request by using Ajax I don't receive anything. Here is my JavaScript :

```
mailHandlerURL:'mail.php',

...

// on submit when all validations are OK
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:_.mailHandlerURL,

    data:{
        name:_.getValFromLabel($('.name',_.form)),
        email:_.getValFromLabel($('.email',_.form)),
        phone:_.getValFromLabel($('.phone',_.form)),
        message:_.getValFromLabel($('.message',_.form)),
        stripHTML:_.stripHTML
    },
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
        _.showFu(); // to display to the user that the email has been sent
    }
})
```

console.log() shows : "mail sent" so the mail.php is called correctly.

The application is hosted on OpenShift and uses PHP 5.4

Comment: I assume you have some kind of validation to verify that the variables you use in your from/subject aren't garbage?

Comment: Yes, regular expressions on the JavaScript side and PHP verifications on server side.